how to style react flip number
I want to create visitor counter for my website. I use api to get hit counter and using react flip number. I want to create something like this

But after using react flip number counter become like this

i want to ask how to style counter with react flip number and give space between number like the example
here my code
 type visitortype={
      count: number;
    }


const Footer = () => {
  const [visitor, setvisitor] = useState<visitortype>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(allvisitor=>  setvisitor(allvisitor))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

 return (
    <GridItem
      w="100%"
      h={{ base: "80px", lg: "300px" }}
      colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
    >
      <VStack
        align={{ base: "center", lg: "stretch" }}
        marginTop={{ base: "0", lg: "60px" }}
        marginLeft={{ base: "0", lg: "50px" }}
      >
        <Box w={{ base: "100px", lg: "220px" }} paddingBottom={"10px"}>
          <Image src={imgLogoMd} alt="Logo" w="100%" />
          <HStack>

             <FlipNumbers 
          height={25} 
           width={20}  
           color="white" 
           background="#8D0000"
           numberStyle={{
            fontSize: 16,
          }}
           play perspective={100} 
           numbers={`${visitor?.count ?? 0}`}/>;

          </HStack>
        </Box>
      </VStack>
    </GridItem>
  );

};


Is this the library you're using? https://github.com/beekai-oss/react-flip-numbers

@alexanderbird yes i use that

I suggest that you frame this question as a CSS question: if you take the HTML that is produced by rendering that component, you could ask "what CSS can I write to make this HTML look like this picture?"
You could use the snippet feature in stack overflow to show your CSS and HTML and what they look like, then someone can copy that into their answer and tweak the CSS as needed to sort out the spacing between the letters.

thanks i will try your suggestion
